# Mezzanine Debug = False issue

Tags: django, mezzanine

In my mezzanine based django project I have Debug = False set within my settings.py file

However, when visiting a url that does not exist my project still throws this error:

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Is there a second location where Debug needs to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you need to change it in `local_settings.py`, which overrides `settings.py` variables in a Mezzanine project by default.

While sometimes useful, running the development server with `DEBUG = False` is not a use case Mezzanine is designed to support out of the box and you may encounter buggy behavior. I recommend primarily using `DEBUG = True` with the development server and `DEBUG = False` with your production server.